# Login credentails get reflected in Registration Form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC project. At the time of login i have saved login credentials(**User Id and Password**) in the browser(Chrome). In this application there is Member Registration Form. When i am login to application and go to Register new member, login credentials get automatically reflected in *User Id and Password* Fields.

[image]

I have try with different way to get User Id and Password fields blank at the time of get registration form.

1) Set `autocomplete="off"` at form level and field level.

2) Set User Id and Password fields blank using JQuery.

3) Set User Id and Password attributes blank in model attribute object on controller.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: What if you change id and name of the inputs to e.g. newUserRegistrationId, newUserRegistrationPassword?

Comment: I have already tried this but still i am getting same problem

Comment: @Viraj Dhamal did you changed the id="" and name="" attributes value, try changing both to something else.

Comment: @ ankur: I have did same as you mentioned but still credentials get reflected

Comment: @VirajDhamal maybe silly to ask, can you see in dom, are your latest id's getting reflected.

Comment: @ ankur: If i don't save login credentials then UserID and Password fields are blank so latest Ids not getting reflected

Comment: @VirajDhamal can try using `$("#Password").val("");` on page load

Comment: @ ankur-singhal: Already did

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following Javascript code, that initialize the username and password values when the page is loaded:

```
function resetValues() {
   document.getElementById("username").value = "";
   document.getElementById("password").value = "";
}
window.addEventListener("load", resetValues);
```

This is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9bwrqhw1/).